# Programmatically created UITabBarController - SIGABRT when click to tabBar

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios5

I tried to create UITabBarController programmatically, but I have a SIGABRT when I click to tabBarItem.

Source:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] init];

    vc1.title = @"vc1";
    vc2.title = @"vc2";

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

    self.view = tabBarController.view;
}
```

Comment: Oh..

I've found, that if UITabBarController is rootViewController - it is work fine, but if it isn't rootViewController - it doesn't work.

I solve this problem following way:

    self.view = tabBarController.view;

changed to

    UIWindow *frontWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    frontWindow.rootViewController = tabController;

Thank you :P

Comment: Igor, you can change your comment into an answer and then click the tick to accept it - then this question will show up as answered.  The code will also be easier to read. :-)